# Mount local folder into Docker container

Tags: docker

I am learning docker and encountered the following issue recently.

I pulled a public image `adkosmos/decryptor:latest`. The image takes a path to a file as an argument and prints out some output. I want this image to access the local file secret.txt in folder local_folder.

I tried to use the command -v:

```
docker run -v /local_folder:/target_folder adkosmos/decryptor:latest /target_folder/secret.txt
```

But it does not work and the scripts that is executed by the image returns the error:

```
AssertionError: No such file /target_folder/secret.txt
```

I thought that -v command allows to synchronize local folder and some folder in the container.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is inside this directory? Is there a target_file.txt and a secret.txt?

Comment: Just secret.txt. It is the same file actually, I changed the name.

Comment: Have you tried with argument like: `-v ./local_folder:/target_folder`, since `/local_folder` will look from your root directory, where that folder probably doesn't exist.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the "/target_folder/secret.txt" at the end. The file should be available on the running container since you are mounting it.

Comment: The python script inside the container accepts a path to the file and then process it. So, I tried to run the image passing "/target_folder/secret.txt" as an argument. I expected to see the output of the program inside the image.

Comment: Given the message, I suppose that I did a mistake and instead I should have added "/local_folder/secret.txt" , right? Because before I've mounted local_folder into the container? Initially I thought that the file would be copied to the target_folder.